# Ubuntu 18.04 Won't Boot: Device dev-disk-by Timed Out & Dependencies Failed

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dependencies

With a Lenovo Legion Y520-IKBN running Win10, I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to dual-boot my machine. Aside from some initial NVIDIA driver issues, the last month has been smooth sailing until a few nights ago. I had been downloading and installing various applications and rebooted my system a few times. Moreover, I tried several methods to fix the night-light feature (which stopped working) by moving and deleting some files. Regardless, the last time I tried to reboot I saw the following and I'm not sure what is wrong and how to proceed. Thanks

[image]

Things got stuck here so I did a hard reset and got the following:

[image]

[image]